# php, jquery, load function and page address

Tags: php, jquery

i have two files.
In first (parent, address: www.myaddress.com/fun/test.php) is jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        import_f = setInterval(function()
        {
            $('#file').load('fun2.php?id='+ Math.random());

        }, 5000);       
    });
});         
</script>
```

When i print in fun2.php file full page address, i get: /fun2.php?id=0.31089064538474454.

How get paren page address. (www.myaddress.com/fun/test.php).

Parent's address may always be another, so I need to find a function that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what your looking for?

```
function getParentAddress(){
  return window.location;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the [**HTTP Referrer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). You can get it via [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

But note that this can be changed by the user to something else, so you actually cannot rely on that.

---

Maybe it is better to send the current URL via the Ajax call, along with the ID:

```
$('#file').load('fun2.php?id='+ Math.random() +'&parent=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location));
```

But again, if one really wants to, he can change this too. So you can never 100% trust that one request is really coming from a certain page.

Reference: [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

The current address of the page is stored in the window.location property.

```
console.log(window.location)
```

run on this page yields

```
hash: ""
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031148/php-jquery-load-function-and-page-address"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/4031148/php-jquery-load-function-and-page-address"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
search: ""
```